# Assign value to a variable using || operator with if condition in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to write logic for a search query. There are many different conditions with different parameters. One parameter sent from form is `code`. So there are `code` values in two different tables: `competitions` and `responses`. What I need is to check the `params[:code]` value first in `competitions` table and if it does not exist then check in `responses` table. If it does not exist in either table then it should return `nil`. I am trying to write it in a single `if` statement. The code I tried is below:

```
competitions = Competition.includes(:event, :responses)
if params[:code].present?
  competitions = (competitions.where(code: params[:code])) || 
  (competitions.joins(:responses).where(responses: { code: params[:code] }))
```

The above code checks only the value of `competitions.where(code: params[:code])`. If that value is `[]`, then it is not evaluating the second condition. What changes should I do to make the above code work as per the requirements mentioned above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`competitions.where(code: params[:code])` returns a `Relation` object which is always truthy.

Luckily enough, it implements `#presence` method, returning either the value if it’s not blank, or `nil`. So, this should work:

```rb
competitions.where(code: params[:code]).presence || ...
```